# SSO request process in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring-boot web application which has a login page and spring security follows. Now I have to put my web application as SSO from another web application. They are going to provide a link on their website as https://testMyWebApp/login?userId=TestUser1&password=123 when anyone clicks on this link it should show the welcome page in my app instead of the login page(seeking username and password). Currently my web app processes request from login page only.Can anyone guide me how I can integrate my web app to process this SSO request from another web app there by not disturbing the current login process?

Current Login logic is as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {       
        try {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/css/**","/js/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll()                   
                     .defaultSuccessUrl("/TestController/load", true)
                    .and()                    
                .sessionManagement()
                    .invalidSessionUrl(loginPage)
                    .and()                   
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/welcome")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl(loginPage)
                    .permitAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        try {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService detailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new PasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        AuthenticationProviderImpl provider = new AuthenticationProviderImpl();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService());
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom pre authentication filter where you can check the parameteres and do authentication in the background. Like this:

```
http.addFilter(yourCustomFilter())
.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider())
.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService())
```

and the method `yourCustomFilter()` can look like this.

```
@Bean
public AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter tomcatRemoteUserFilter() throws Exception {
    final AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter abstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter = new AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter() {
        @Override protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
            final Principal userPrincipal = request.getUserPrincipal();
            log.info("User Principal: "+userPrincipal);
            //DO YOUR CHECKS
            return "someUserId";


        }

        @Override protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return "N/A";
        }

    };
    abstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    return abstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter;
}
```

As authentication Provider you should then also use a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` that gets your `UserDetailsService` e.g.

```
@Bean
public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider() {
    final PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
   preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<>(customUserDetailsService()));
    return preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider;
}
```

Comment: Hi mrkernelpanic, thanks for your response. do you mean to add something like this : http.addFilter(tomcatremoteUserFilter()).authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/css/**","/js/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated(). ------  Moreover In my code i have a custom authentication provider defined in configureGlobal() can't i use that?

Comment: Sure should reuse your existing code, it is just a proposal how it works, the exact code is on your side :) Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes i tried the method but i'm still stuck at where i can verify user id with password because here in getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal method only the user id is being passed.

Comment: Typically you do that in your UserService